# Como faço, para criar um Makefile em C

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

Estou a ter problemas na execução do makefile.

```
main:   ex09.o  funcao1.o
    gcc -c ex09.o   funcao1.o -o main

ex09.o: ex09.c
    gcc -c ex09.c

funcao1.o:      funcao1.c   funcao1.h
    gcc -c funcao1.c

clean:  
    rm *.o
```

Um dos erros de linker que é gerado

```
gcc -c ex09.o   funcao1.o -o main
gcc: warning: ex09.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc: warning: funcao1.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso aqui está errado

```
main:   ex09.o  funcao1.o
    gcc -c ex09.o   funcao1.o -o main ### BAD
```

porque "-c" e "-o" ao mesmo não faz sentido: "-c" diz para só compilar e não criar o executável, no entanto "-o" diz para criar o executável.

O certo é assim:

```
main:   ex09.o  funcao1.o
    gcc ex09.o   funcao1.o -o main ### GOOD
```

sem o "-c".

Comment: Agora o erro que me aparece é este : gcc ex09.o funcao1.o -o main funcao1.o: In function sort_without_resp': funcao1.c:(.text+0xa8): multiple definition of sort_without_resp' ex09.o:ex09.c:(.text+0xa): first defined here collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [main] Error 1 - @ José X.

Comment: @ José X: Pra ser preciso, o `-o` serve para dizer o nome do arquivo gerado. É possível usar o `-c` para só compilar um arquivo fonte e ao mesmo tempo o `-o` para indicar o nome do arquivo objeto. Mas eu desconheço qualquer uso prático pra isso.

Comment: @C. E. Gesser é, eu "simplifiquei" um pouquinho.

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema não é exatamente no Makefile. O arquivo está com a sintaxe correta, indicando as dependências, os alvos e como gerá-los. O problema está no comando para gerar o executável final, em relação à flag que você está passando para o gcc.

Na primeira linha, responsável por linkar o executável final, você está passando a flag `-c`, que serve para pedir ao gcc que apenas compile o arquivo fonte, sem linkar. Nesse caso você quer justamente o contrário.

Portanto basta remover o `-c` da primeira linha do seu Makefile que ele deve funcionar como você espera.

Comment: Agora o erro que me aparece é este :                                                gcc ex09.o funcao1.o -o main
funcao1.o: In function `sort_without_resp':
funcao1.c:(.text+0xa8): multiple definition of `sort_without_resp'
ex09.o:ex09.c:(.text+0xa): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1 - @ C.E.Gesser

Comment: @Programador Agora parece ser outro problema, não relacionado com esta questão. Parece que uma função sua está definida em mais de uma unidade de compilação. Isso pode acontecer se, por exemplo, você escrever o corpo da função no arquivo .h.